# Как убрать дубликаты из словаря Python

Tags: python, dict

Подскажите как отсортировать словарь только в рамках значений. Должно получиться так:

```
tasks = {
    0: ["Покормить кота","Покормить кота"],
    1: ["Покормить кота", "Забрать посылку"]
}

# Результат:
new_tasks = {
    0: ['Покормить кота'], 
    1: ['Покормить кота', 'Забрать посылку']
}
```

Comment: И как? Где пример?

Comment: Добро пожаловать! удалите ваш ответ, под вопросом нажмите [edit] и добавьте ваши данные текстом.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

*Решение:*

```
new_tasks = {key: list(set(tasks[key])) for key in tasks}
```

(или: см. конец ответа).

---

*Результат (в переменной `new_tasks`):*

```
{0: ['Покормить кота'], 1: ['Покормить кота', 'Забрать посылку']}
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Я применил стандартную функцию `set()`, чтобы сделать *множество* из списка.

Таким образом Питон **автоматически удалил дубликаты,** потому что в множестве дубликатов не может быть по определению.

Затем я превратил это множество *обратно в список* применением стандартной функции `list()`.

---

*Более подробное объяснение:*

Ваш оригинальный список можно представить себе как

```
{key: tasks[key]     for key in tasks}
```

Но и теперь на значение ключа `key`, т.е. на

`tasks[key]`

(оригинальный список с возможными дубликатами)
примените выше упомянутые функции `set()` и `list()`, получая

`list(set(tasks[key]))`

---

*Примечание:*

Кому-то может более понравиться решение

```
new_tasks = {key: list(set(value)) for key, value in tasks.items()}
```

(Может быть и мне. ;-))